# QGIS 1.8.0 Mac where is measure window or measure area symbol?

Tags: qgis, area, mac

Just trying to measure the area of a selected polygon (a few km2) but can't find out where the measure symbol is (mentioned in some posts here) or how to get the measure window shown in the manual. How?

Answer (score 1):

The measure tool is in the Attributes Tool Bar. If it isn't visible you can bring it up using  View > Toolbars and check the Attributes Toolbar.

The measuring tool icon is a blue rule with a line above it.  It has a drop down menu to chose measurement type, Length, Area or Angle.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Found it, but I can't get it to measure an existing polygon, it only seems to measure the area of something drawn on the map live. Do I really have to retrace the 100+ points of a polygon I want to measure the area of when it's already created in a layer?

Comment: John. I've only ever used it to measure area by plotting round an existing polygon. It drags the measured area out as you have probably seen. I don't know if you can use it to just specify an existing polygon to work on and have it give you the area. I suspect there must be a way to do this but I'm afraid I don't know the method.

Comment: I've submitted it as a feature request, with a note that if QGIS already does it, to answer here. cross fingers!

Comment: I hope you get a result John.